# Need to hyperlink only URL that should open in new window after clicking

Tags: lightning-aura-components

We have a scenario where Success guidance is a rich text area field in that  text are available along with URLS. That filed values are displayed in lightning components but in lightning component the URL is inactive.So, my requirement is to make only URL hyperlinked and active so that when we ckick on that it opens in a new window:

Below are some rich text area value:

1. Guidance for Success
   Work with your FSL to determine areas of the city for your office. The website www.loopnet.com is an online resource for commercial real estate. Your FSL also has access to more detailed commercial real estate availability through CoStar. Ensure you read through the attached guides for details on commercial real estate, negotiating a lease, and Allstate's standards and guidelines.

--> in the above texts we want to hyperlink only "www.loopnet.com " remaining text will be same how it is.

2. Guidance for Success
   Information on the Agency Technology Store (which is part of a broader program called "Agency Desktop Reinvention"), including a link to log in, can be found on Gateway at: https://agencygateway.allstate.com/wps/myportal/id/172620

---> In the above texts , we want to hyperlink onl "https://agencygateway.allstate.com/wps/myportal/id/172620" so that when we click on this link it should open in new window.

Here is the piece of code that we have written in lightning component:

```
<aura:if isTrue="{! (v.task.Description == 'Not Applicable')}">
                                    <strong><span class="slds-text-title">Guidance for Success : Not Applicable</span></strong>

                                    <aura:set attribute="else">
                                        <strong><span class="slds-text-title">Guidance for Success</span></strong>
                                        <p class="slds-p-top_x-small">{!v.task.Description}</p>  
                                    </aura:set>
                                </aura:if>
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You can use <a href="#">www.loopnet.com</a>.This will make only the website you mentioned in hyperlink.

Comment: But the thing is entire description is coming from rich text  area field. so,want to know how I can filter this url from entire texts and hyperlink it.. I have given 2 scenarios in which URL has to be hyperlinked.

Comment: Please  have a look at above 2 text area field values..